# Partial Derivative when it depend on two dependent variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If a function  $f(x,y)$ is dependent on x and y, and $y(x)$ is dependent on x. Then what is  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} $. Does it = $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} $+$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} $ or does it equal just $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} $ ? Thanks a lot. This is a example of a mixed up case different from what I learned, so I am confused.

Thank you. This is the context: I am trying to calculate $ \frac{\partial (x^0)'}{\partial x^1} $ in the context of special relativity. whereas $(x^0)'=ct'$ is time term in the new frame, $x^0=ct$ is time term in the resting frame, and $x^1$ is the x coordinate of the resting frame. From special relativity we have, $(x^0)'=\gamma(x^0-\beta x^1)$. And  $ \frac{\partial x^1}{\partial x^0}$ is not zero but it equals to$\frac{v}{c}$

Comment: can you give an example of such function for more clarification?

Comment: Great question. Unfortunately there is no general correct answer, and it might mean one or the other definition, depending on the context